# Loop Help! Adding multiple markers to maps api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

EDIT!

I see that I'm overwriting my lat long values before they reach the onPostExecute. It was suggested that I use an array to store the info before passing off to onPostExecute. I thought arrays could only hold 1 object per index. And since I want to preserve multiple contact items (phone, address, email etc) per index what do I do? For example with each marker point I want to not only pull the lat long value but also the name to add to the marker.

/EDIT!

I'm trying to add multiple markers through maps api v2. I pull the addresses through a JSON string. When I run it I only get the last address to display as a marker on the map. How would I alter the loop below to get it to display each marker. (The add marker is located in a onPostExecute) Thanks!

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {

    public Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();

  try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                     lati = location1.getLatitude();
                         longi = location1.getLongitude();

                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);


     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;


    }
         // ADD MARKER TO MAP UI
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
         .title("Hello world"));
    }  

    }
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only getting the last position because every time you are overwriting `lati` and`longi` before you get to the onPostExecute.

you need to store the points in an array or something and then return them to the onPostExecute

Comment: I'm going to want to set the title of each marker to the name of each contact. How do I preserve the contact items along with the new lat long values in an Array?

Comment: create an object and return an array of the object with all the information